# VS Express 2012 for Desktop doesn't make 32bit compatible apps

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Recently used VS Express 2012 for Desktop and I work in a 64bit machine and the vb.net apps made in VS 2012 do not run in 32 bit machines!
error msgs "not a valid 32bit application"

In VS Express 2010 it worked fine, but in VS 2012, even if I chose the Any CPU, x86 configs, the released apps do not work in 32bit machines.

Comment: Is it a "Hello World" app, or something complex? Are you using any 3rd party libraries which have both x86 and x64 version?

Comment: @HansPassant: You are wrong. Created simple Winforms app (only form, nothing else) with VS2012 Express for DT on W7-Ult-x64. Copied release folder to (VM'ed) Win XP Pro 32. Program runs.

Comment: @HansPassant. Since when are VB.Net apps "native" apps?

Comment: There's something strange about this question, the Platform Target setting couldn't be changed in earlier versions of Express, you had to edit the project file by hand.  No idea if that changed in VS2012, but the shoe fits.

Comment: @HansPassant: Configuration manager is now available in Express.

Comment: That doesn't help, the Platform name has no effect on a VB.NET project's Platform Target setting.  In the retail edition of VS2012 the setting is available at Project + Properties, Compile tab, Target CPU combobox.

Comment: @HansPassant: **available at Project + Properties, Compile tab, Target CPU combobox** -> same with Express now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are perhaps changing the platform for the Debug configuration only. On the Compile tab of the Settings page there is a Configuration drop-down, change that to 'All Configurations' and then change the Platform to x86. Save > Re-Publish.